# Intersections of nested intervals

Tags: real-analysis, interval-arithmetic

[image]

Hello,

I have the following question and I would really need help finding the examples they are looking for. I can prove the rest but I’m never good at finding examples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a): $I_n=[n, \infty)$.

(b): $I_n=(0, \frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: Thanks @Fred! I am not sure how the first one is closed though

Comment: what is the complement of $ I_n$ ?

Comment: so for a set to be closed, its complement must be open?

Comment: and its complement is (-inf, n)